# Why Moses named his son Eliezer "after" Avraham's slave?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, moshe-rabbeinu, parashat-lech-lecha, parashas-yisro

> "וַיֹּאמֶר אַבְרָם ה"א מַה תִּתֶּן לִי וְאָנֹכִי הוֹלֵךְ עֲרִירִי וּבֶן מֶשֶׁק בֵּיתִי הוּא דַּמֶּשֶׂק אֱלִיעֶזֶר." ([Gen 15,2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0115.htm#2))
>
> "וְשֵׁם הָאֶחָד אֱלִיעֶזֶר כִּי אֱלֹהקי אָבִי בְּעֶזְרִי וַיַּצִּלֵנִי מֵחֶרֶב פַּרְעֹה." ([Ex 18,4](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0218.htm#4))

The Torah says nothing about why Avraham's slave was called Eliezer, but rather ascribes the explanation to Moses' son. (*I titled it "after" not really "in respect to" but chronologically after*).

Some questions arise:

- Why the slave was called (all of sudden) Eliezer?
- Moses should have known about Avraham's slave, did he call his son after him?
- Those are the only two Eliezers in the Torah (there are some more in the Nakh) - what's the connection? Like Baal Haturim likes to draw parallels.

Comment: marginally related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88995/16354

Comment: Abraham’s brother and grandfather were both Nachor. Noach’s grandfather and Kayin’s killer were both Lamech. Rivkah’s nursemaid and one of the prophetesses were both Devorah. There’s lots of names duplicated in Tanach; why does this one in particular surprise you?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.44.9?lang=bi

Comment: @JoelK when providing hints please elaborate what point does it prove. THe Midrash says the Gematria of Eliezer is 318, so what?

Comment: @DonielF 1. All the examples you brought were Goyim and there's no surprise, I agree, 2. None of the above names was explained 3. the Torah says the slave was already named so, so Moses did no invent the name, he maybe just chose it because "אלקי אבי בעזרי" but the name was already used. That's why I originally called it "named after".

Comment: @Gary but if there are 2 Jews it has to  be 3 questions.

Comment: Time expiration....let me correct my typos please: A couple(not 3, as in your "couple")of questions arise: How do you know Eliezer was "all of a sudden" Eliezer? Is there a Midrash somewhere that says Abram/Abraham named him that for a reason?  Second, Eliezer was a faithful, good person, as the Torah describes him. What makes you think Moses would be prejudiced against naming a son after such a person? And why would there have to be a connection, if it was used both in Torah and Nach times.  It was just a Biblical name.

Comment: Earlier in the medrash it brings an opinion that says that Damesek Eliezer is Lot, and Avraham called him that because G-d helped him against the four kings.

Comment: @JoelK A good point, how do we continue from here?

Comment: It's something of an answer to your first question (Why the slave was called (all of sudden) Eliezer?) - although this opinion doesn't actually seem to believe that Avraham had a slave called Eliezer at all...

Answer (score 4):

[Radak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Kimhi) writes in his commentary to Genesis 15:2 that Abraham gave his servant the name Eliezer:

> או אפשר שהיה שמו דמשק כשבא אל אברם והוא קרא אותו אליעזר כי אליעזר לשון עברי הוא

Why he specifically chose the name Eliezer may be based on the Midrash in Bereishit Rabbah Parshah 44:

> הוא דמשק אליעזר שבשבילו רדפתי מלכים עד דמשק ועזרני האל

Here it seems that the name Eliezer is a contraction of the Hebrew words "God" and "helped me". This is the very reason given in Exodus 18:4 for why Moses named his son Eliezer.

So to answer your questions, we can say that both Abraham and Moses named someone Eliezer because they both wanted to commemorate the fact that they were helped by God. This may in fact have been entirely a coincidence, as I don't see any reason to assume that Moses was even aware that Abraham had a servant named Eliezer. Abraham's Eliezer is not exactly a major character – he is only named once in the Torah – and the Torah hadn't been given yet when Moses named his son.

Comment: thank you, I asked a similar question about יהודית, that clearly had no relations with Judaism. But your answer seems very plausible. Regarding EliEzer - there are many Gizrot that a name can be derived, so it didn't have to be the very same name. The fact it IS probably means something.